# What would the pitch accent be for 言うた（ゆうた） vs. the name ユウタ?

Tags: pitch-accent

I couldn't find information on either when I searched, so I was wondering if there was any difference. I would assume it might vary between regions, so in a region where ゆうた is used for 言った

Answer (score 2):

ゆうた (dialectal 言った) and ゆうた (優太, 裕太, etc) are pronounced the same, ゆうた【HLL】.

Comment: Your answer is probably correct 99% of the time but surely there exists some dialect where they are not the same. I found [this page](http://www.furusato-tanegashima.net/tanegashima/hougen.html) claiming they say いうた in Tanegashima (Kagoshima prefecture). Tanegashima has its own pitch accent system so these may not be the same in that dialect.

Comment: @Ketchup901 Yes, different dialects has different accent systems. According to [this map](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%84%A1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88#%E5%88%86%E5%B8%83%E5%9C%B0%E5%9F%9F), Tanegashima is labelled as 曖昧アクセント, but some dialects are totally accent-less. 言うた is basically Osaka-dialect, so I at least considered Osaka-ben, but 言うた and 裕太 are pronounced the same there, too.